# How to set result format for queries in Apache Derby ij tool

Tags: derby

Is there a way to "pretty print" the query results in the ij? The default results look quite incomprehensible due to the fact that columns are thrown here and there in the query results.

In PostgreSQL, there's the /pset command to control results from pgsql commands, I'm lookin something like that for Derby.

Comment: That's always been one of my gripes about ij.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy using a tool like SQL Squirrel, which has a nice UI for letting me re-size and re-order columns, view data in different ways, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the first N characters of a column, try casting it to varchar(N), like so:

```
SELECT CAST(foo AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM bar;
```

That way you can avoid having one long column spill over onto several lines.